# How to measure the energy required to pedal an exercise bike

Tags: energy, measurements, torque

I have hacked a FitDesk exercise bike to output the RPM of the pedals and the position of the resistance control within its range of travel.

I want to characterize the energy that is required to pedal the bike at different RPMs and resistance settings.

My approach is to determine the torque required to the turn the bike at different settings.

My first idea is to use a variable speed drill to turn the bike while measuring the amperage the drill is pulling.  Keeping the drill speed constant, I would change the resistance setting and observe the change in amperage.  I would also baseline the amperage pulled with no load on the drill.

I am able to turn the bike using the drill, but I am worried that the measurements will be non-linear because the amount of heat generated by the drill changes quite a bit as resistance is added and I don't know how this relates to the amperage reading.

My second idea is to drop a weight which will turn the bike using a simple pulley arrangement.  If I know the weight and can measure the angular acceleration of the bike, I should be able to calculate how much torque the weight is overcoming at different resistance settings.

But I am worried that after setting all that up, the differences in acceleration will be too small for meaningful comparison.  (I really have no idea if this would be a problem or not.)

So I ask the experts: what is the easiest way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Measuring static torque is a lot easier that measuring torque at speed. Maybe looking at the time needed to decelerate from some speed to another speed while not powered.

Comment: @ja72 Wow, that never occurred to me.  It's certainly an easier experiment to perform.  Thanks.

Comment: @ja72 So that would give me some relative measurements between settings.  Without knowing the mass of the flywheel and other wheels in the system, I would still need another measurement to get the torque required in absolute terms, correct?

Comment: You might be able to estimate the inertial properties of the flywheel, but you need to figure out the gearing also. With that and the deceleration you can get torque.